# Python string compare issue

Tags: python, list, compare, substring

I've got some code that looks like this:

```
    valid = set()
    for string in substrings:
       for line in dictionary_words:
           if string in line:
               valid.add(string)
    f.writelines(sorted(valid))
```

Both dictionary_words and substrings are currently lists.

After the `substring` is found inside any `dictionary_words`, it should just go ahead and move onto the next `substring`.

What is the best way of writing that?

Comment: @F.C.: why not post this as an answer, since it is exactly what the O.P. is asking for ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
valid = set()
for string in substrings:
  for line in dictionary_words:
      if string in line:
          valid.add(string)
          break
f.writelines(sorted(valid))
```

@F.C.: If you use `continue` instead of `break`, it will run the next iteration of the inner for-loop.

Comment: Would using 'break' jump to the next "line in dictionary_words" or to the next "string in substrings"?

Comment: If there were a statement on the same indentation level as `for line in ...` after break, it would jump there. But as there is nothing, it would continue with the next `string in substrings`

Comment: @Srikar: I think making it a dictionary, and using `dictionary_of_dictionary_words.has_key(string)` would not work, as `string in line` does substring matching, and has_key does not. Or maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: That's awesome, thank you.  And 'continue' would move to the next 'line in dictionary_words' I gather, is that correct?

Comment: Yes. Therefore not having any benefit, as it would not alter the flow of the program.

Comment: I knew there was a straightforward way of doing this, thank you very much!  Also, you are dead on about the substring matching on the other answer, I'm not looking for exact matches here, but partials.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try this -

```
    valid = set()
    for string in substrings:
       if dictionary_words.has_key(string):
           valid.add(string)
    f.writelines(sorted(valid))
```

There is no need for the extra for-loop inside the main for-loop. This `has_key` solves your issue of moving on to the next substring is `string` is not in `dictionary_word`.

hope this helps...

Comment: dictionary_words is a list, although I could probably make it a tuple.

Comment: make `dictionary_words` a `dict()`. since you are interested in lookup, it'll be a whole lot faster than a `list` or a `tuple`

Comment: dictionary_words was a list, although I could probably make it a dictionary.  Sorry, that was obviously confusing in the question in hindsight.

Answer (score 1):

The following (untested code) should be equivalent to your loops:

```
valid =  set(s for s in substrings for ln in dictionary_words if s in ln)
```

In Python 3.0 you could use a set comprehension:

```
valid = {s for s in substrings for ln in dictionary_words if s in ln}
```

Slightly more efficient:

```
valid =  set(s for s in substrings if any(s in ln for ln in dictionary_words))
```

Comment: No problem, the last line is actually more like what you are looking for, and is equivalent to adding the `break` statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
[valid.add(my_string) for my_string in substrings for line in dictionary_words if my_string in line]
f.writelines(sorted(valid))
```

Using [List Comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) would be faster using loops in the way you have implemented.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Sadly, the loops were better than my last version of it, which was truly ugly.  I'll read up on list comprehensions.

Comment: You can also write list comps as your traditional loops for better readability, (although I prefer the default list comp style)...